# Django get user like from friend list

Tags: python, django

I'm a Django beginner, I have a friend field in Profile Model which list all my friend users. And also these friends liked my post. How do I get the names of only those users in my friends list to display in the post they liked.

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,... )
    friends = models.ManyToManyField('Profile',related_name='my_friends')

class FriendRequest(models.Model):
    to_user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,... ) 
    from_user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,... ) 

class Post(models.Model):
    poster_profile = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,... )
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='image_likes')

def home(request):
    all_images = Post.objects.filter(poster_profile=request.user) 
    img = Post.objects.filter(likes__profile__friends__user=request.user)

{% if all_images %}
{% for post in all_images %}

#all_images code here 

{{ post. likes.count }} #like count

{% for image in img %}<img src="{{ image.profile.profile_pic.url }}"> {% endfor %}#The profile_pic do not display 

{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: If you have a `post` then `post.likes.all()` are all the users that liked a post. `post.likes.filter(profile__friends=some_user)` will only show users that liked the post and are also friends of `some_user`.

Comment: @dirkgroten....i don't understand your logic, can you attached your answer to my question so I can understand your logic

Comment: Show us how you are displaying one post.

Comment: @dirkgroten... I have update my question, please check

Answer (score 0):

if someone isn't your friend you can prevent him to like or even see (or comment) your post , or for each user who likes your post check if he is in your friend list then add him to a new emty list then render this list

Comment: @Hamdi...how do I get each user in my friend list who like a particular post? How do I filter this in views?

Comment: @Oghomwen you get your friends  ` my_friends = user.profile.friends.all()                                                                                                                                                                                             
  post = post.objects.filter(poster_profile = request.user.profie )                                   
  post_likes = post.likes.all() `                                                                                                         now you only need to get the intersection between my_friends and post_likes

Comment: Can you post it as an answer, the code is not properly understood in the comment section

Comment: @Hassen...The profile_pic of the user do not display, why? I used img = Post.objects.filter(likes__profile__friends__user=request.user) and template: {% for post in img %}<img src="{{ post.profile.profile_pic.url }}"> {% endfor%}

Answer (score 0):

Change your queryset in your view to this:

```
from django.db.models import Count, Q

all_images = Post.objects\
    .filter(poster_profile=request.user)\
    .annotate(likes_count=Count(
        'likes', 
        distinct=True, 
        filter=Q(likes__profile__friends=request.user.profile))
```

then in your template each `post` has the annotation `likes_count` so you can do `{{ post.likes_count }}`.

Comment: what's 'Andy'? I haven't written "Andy" in my answer. Look at your error trace, identify the line of code **in your own code** where the error is happening (start at the bottom of the trace, going line by line to the top until you see a line that belongs to your code) and then tell us that specific line and tell us the full error.

Comment: Andy is the current_user. The error is point at:
        filter=Q(likes__profile__friends=request.user))

Comment: I fixed the query, but still I don't see how you'd get this specific error. You should show your entire `home` view

Comment: The profile_pic of the user do not display, why? I used img = Post.objects.filter(likes__profile__friends__user=request.user) and template: {% for post in img %}<img src="{{ img.profile.profile_pic.url }}"> {% endfor%}

Comment: `img` is your queryset of posts. So in template you can’t do `img.profile`

Comment: Typo, I meant {{ post.profile.profile_pic.url }} this doesn't display the image